# most popular rides at disneyland tokyo

Tags: tokyo, disney

To make the most of a Disneyworld trip it's often advisable to wake up early and be at the park right when they open. Get the super popular rides out of the way right when the park opens, before the lines start to build up, and then do the less popular rides later in the evening.

In order to make this work, however, you have to know what the popular rides are.

For Disneyworld there are websites like https://touringplans.com/walt-disney-world/touring-plans and books like [Unofficial Guide to Walt Disney World 2019](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1628090812) that are updated every year with the latest info.

My question is...  are there similar sites or books for Disneyland Tokyo (or any of the other Disneyland's?)

I guess a related question to this...  in my experience with Disneyworld, if you're sufficiently aggressive (as I described above), I'd say it's possible to do each of the four parks (Magic Kingdom, Epcot, Hollywood Studios and Animal Kingdom) in a day. Disneyland Tokyo (or more generally every other Disneyland) seems to be equivalent to one of the four parks at Disneyworld so if one park can be done in a day for Disneyworld then would it be fair to say that Disneyland Tokyo could probably also be done in a day?

Comment: There seems to be no shortage of blog posts about Tokyo Disneyland, e.g. [top 5 this and that](https://livejapan.com/en/in-tokyo/in-pref-chiba/in-chiba_suburbs/article-a0002464/), [longest lines](https://tdrexplorer.com/best-tokyo-disneyland-attractions-fastpass-guide/), [what to prioritize](https://www.disneytouristblog.com/tokyo-disneyland-best-ride-guide/), etc.

Answer (score 4):

When doing that sort of wating-time hacking, an extremely useful tool is the Disneyland Fastpass app, which (even if you're not a ticket holder) will let you see waiting times for all the major rides in real-time. Watching those times progress, particularly on the day of the week when you plan to go, can give you a good feel for what fills up quickly and what lines stay short throughout the day.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Disney Land and Disney Sea can each be done in a day (I have done each in a day riding just about all of the attractions in a single day as well as watching parades and shows)

If you want to battle the Japanese, this site has realtime and historical waiting times for the rides at Disney Land and Disney Sea as well as the fast pass timings:

http://www15.plala.or.jp/gcap/disney/realtime.htm

As I write this, the current popular rides at Disney Land are Space Mountain and Monsters Inc and the current popular rides at Disney Sea are Soarin (new ride, with 4 hour waits from park opening onwards, get your fastpass using the map immediately upon entering the park and even then you might not get it.) and Toy Story